# Can I use Roslyn to accomplish this C# syntax transformation?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Two-part question here about adding C# syntax sugar using Roslyn:

First, is it possible using Roslyn to add new syntax to C#, or does it always have to be a transformation from valid C# to other valid C#? For example, I'd like to do something like VB.NET's XML literals:

```
XElement lvalue = <some><xml /></some>;
```

Is it possible to transform this at compile time to:

```
XElement lvalue = new XElement("some", new XElement("xml")); // or whatever
```

Second, if that's possible, what does it look like to the user? Can I do this such that one writes the first expression, and never sees the transformation to the second expression (it happens transparently at compile-time)? Or do Roslyn syntax transformations have to appear as sort of an IDE "refactoring suggestion"? I'm unclear on this from the Roslyn docs.

Comment: The problem is, this is not sintatically friendly for C#.

Comment: Correct, the first is not valid C# - I want to add new syntax. This specific example would probably involve extending the lexer and parser, then transforming the resulting AST into constructor calls. So the answer is "no?"

Comment: Uh dunnathinkso.  But you could just define all your hard-coded xml in public members of a referenced assembly written in vb.net.  VB currently supports xml literals.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm not trying to do this example per se, just interested in the capabilities of Roslyn with regards to source transformations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> First, is it possible using Roslyn to add new syntax to C#

Nope.

> or does it always have to be a transformation from valid C# to other valid C#?

Yep.

Roslyn is a C#/VB analysis engine; those are the only languages it analyzes. It is *not* for extending the C# or VB languages.

The C# compiler is open sourced under a fairly permissive license. If you want to write your own version of it, you can certainly fork the repository and make the parser do whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

If it has to look the the snippet you provided then no (without having to solve some much bigger problems), however you could go down a similar route that [stackoverflow went with for localisation](http://mattjibson.com/blog/2013/03/01/careers-localization-part-3-extraction/#c-and-razor-extraction-with-roslyn)

You could introduce something like `_x("<some><xml /></some>")`, you don't get much benefit in terms of syntax (cause you could have a runtime method that parses this), but you could have Roslyn take the work of replacing it with the exact code you want it to generate.

Comment: Thanks, is the only way to add genuinely new syntax to patch the compiler, then? Roslyn offers no hooks for this?

Comment: There are no hooks for msbuild/project.json based builds. You don't have to patch the compiler though, but you'd need to take control of the compilation, maybe in a console app, then add the Roslyn package, create a workspace, add the SyntaxWalker via the apis, and then emit your assemblies. It's nowhere near as bad as it sounds, but it still is a lot of effort.

Comment: Got it, so Roslyn does expose APIs for the lexical/syntactic additions I want to do, but the challenges are more around hooking this into the build process?

Comment: Yep, thats right =) I did a bit more digging and found a similar SO Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33335770/2225808 What's interesting is that they (the Roslyn team) are considering adding this and the implications, which would be very cool, but potential for some horrific abuse.

Comment: @user1454265 at SO we use [StackExchange.Precompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Precompilation/)